# End game check in a PentaHex game

Tags: java, algorithm

This is one of the problem i have been working from a long time.This is a game of PentaHexes. A player gets to choose one of the 22 pentaHexes and flip/rotate the pentahex according to his/her need, and place the pentaHex in the grid. In the 2 player version of the game, i have to keep a check on end-of-game scenario. A game ends when one of the player fails to keep a pentaHex on the grid. 
For your reference, the game grid and pentaHexes are shown in the page 40. if you check [this link](http://books.google.com/books?id=Hd0Aa54JgNEC&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=22%20pentahexagon%20game&source=bl&ots=E04W_DhvqI&sig=2aSNbmQ1ycSCkowhMjf7ihBJbd0&hl=en&ei=brCxTsP2Hsistgf-8NWZAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false).

I am looking for an algorithm to do this. I can handle coding !
I can do this with a brute force method which would be something like :

each time a penta hex is placed
find all the unused hexagons in the grid.
check the unused PentaHexes,
get the pattern of PentaHex,
check if you can place any of the pentaHex on the Grid,
if YES,
game is not over.
if NO
game over.

Comment: Where in your code are you having the problem specifically? Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: I am looking for an algorithm to do this. I can handle coding !  <br/>
<br/>
each time a penta hex is placed,  <br/>
find all the unused hexagons in the grid.<br/>  
check the unused PentaHexes,   <br/>
get the pattern of PentaHex,   <br/>
check if you can place any of the pentaHex on the Grid,   <br/>
if YES,   <br/>
game is not over.  <br/>
if NO  <br/>
game over.  <br/>

Comment: You just described your algorithm, now you need to try and implement it. Once you've done that, if you have any problems you can post your code and ask specific questions about it.

Comment: yeah.. but i have problem with the algorithm..!! its not efficient. I feel its better to get the algorithm correct than implementing something which is not efficient. Implementation can be done easily. Getting a good algorithm is difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to optimize something that does not exist yet.

Implement it first, use your brute-force idea, and then when you have something that works to a fashion, you will have a far better understanding of what needs to happen. This is the time when you start optimizing and improving your code.

Very, very, rarely does anyone write a piece of code that is perfect in its first iteration.

Don't fall into the trap of trying have a complete/final design before you code. It is very rare that all contingencies/problems can be foreseen. Use your design as a guideline and scope delimiter; write your first 'draft' program; now you can debug and optimize.

You can code, so you know it is an iterative process.

Comment: I agree it is an iterative process. I will implement my idea first and then try to optimize. But I asked the question here just to avoid getting started with wrong algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is apparently not an issue of not knowing how to solve the problem, but rather a question of *"how do I do better than brute force"*.

Though I haven't studied this game in particular, many similar games in the class of  "making puzzles fit together" turn out to be combinatoric problems that will always suffer from some nasty worst-case behavior.

If you're new to this topic, there's a heck of a lot of reading about it.  Even very simple-seeming games like Minesweeper or Tetris--when looked at in a formal way--do not have ([known!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem)) completely generalized solutions that are significantly better than brute force:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39578/simple-real-life-np-hard-problems

One tool that you have in your arsenal is the idea of a "side-structure" of some kind.  Just to throw a random example out there (which may not be a good idea) you could store a number on each cell saying how many connected cells it can reach.  Each time a piece is added to the board, you could subtract from these numbers to reflect the new reality of the board.  Then label each cell of each piece with the number of connected cells it has.  This would suddenly give you the ability to "short-cut" your searches.  (For instance, you wouldn't have to test any cells which couldn't reach at least 4 other cells, because no pentahex could possibly fit on it!)

The tradeoff though is always in the memory these side structures consume, and the time it takes to keep them up to date.  My off-the-cuff example would probably cost more than it saved in the average pentahex game.  So whether it's worth it depends on your specific cases.

It's good to be sensitive and informed about these issues, but don't let it stop you from writing the inefficient but "correct" version first...and then seeing where and how you could use an optimization boost.

Comment: hey.. thanks a lot for the reply. I will first implement and get it working first and then try to make it more efficient. Thanks a lot for the link.

Comment: i would have up-voted your answer but apparently i need a lil more reputation to do so !!